Multiple regex patterns to get values from list items
I have the list below. I need to extract time values and sum them as a whole from the below list.
The time values can be located in different places - e.g. square brackets, parenthesis, at the end of a line, at the beginning, etc.
I was hoping to use a single regex with multiple OR (|) possibilities to pass through each line in the list and extract the values to be able to add them together.
summary = [
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn (2.5)",
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn - 0.5",
    "2 hours - CHGnnnnnnnnn - some random words",
    "1.25 hours - CHGnnnnnnnnn - more random words",
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn [2],",
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn - yet more words - 2 hrs",
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn, CHGnnnnnnnnn - 4hrs",
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn another word-     2.5",
    "1 hour - CHGnnnnnnnnn -",
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn - 00552988-  3",
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn(30m)",
    "CHGnnnnnnnnn - more words that is not needed - 4.75"
]

This is the code I have so far, which only caters for scenarios where time is matched in square brackets or parenthesis. As soon as I try my regex brain to include the other lines where time is not in brackets, it breaks.
import re

summary = [
    "CHG453689356 (2.5)",
    "CHG190394857(2.5) , CHG000159040 (3)",
    "CHG098764573 [2],"
]

# Define regex pattern to extract hours
time_pattern = re.compile(r'\((\d+(\.\d*)?)\)|\[(\d+(\.\d*)?)\]')

# Initialize total hours accumulator
total_hours_all_lines = 0

# Extract and sum hours for each line
for entry in summary:
    # Initialize total hours accumulator for the current line
    total_hours_line = 0
    
    # Find all matches of time pattern in the entry
    time_matches = time_pattern.findall(entry)
    
    # Iterate over matches and sum the hours for the current line
    for match in time_matches:
        # Check if group 0 has a valid number (for parentheses)
        if match[0]:
            total_hours_line += float(match[0])
        # Check if group 2 has a valid number (for square brackets)
        elif match[2]:
            total_hours_line += float(match[2])

    # Print the total hours for the current line
    print(f"Total hours for line '{entry}': {total_hours_line}")
    
    # Add the current line's total hours to the total for all lines
    total_hours_all_lines += total_hours_line

# Print the total hours for all lines
print(f"Total hours for all lines: {total_hours_all_lines}")

Which outputs:
Total hours for line 'CHG453689356 (2.5)': 2.5
Total hours for line 'CHG190394857(2.5) , CHG000159040 (3)': 5.5
Total hours for line 'CHG098764573 [2],': 2.0
Total hours for all lines: 10.0


Have you tried anything at all? A site like regex101.com can be a great help for experimentation - feel free to ask here if you think you have something that should work, but doesn't in some specific way. Just edit your question and share your own attempts with a description of the specific problem you're having. Also, it looks like your provided some sample data, but your actual data may have characters that would break a solution that would work on this sample. Make sure that what you're sharing is representative of the real data (for example, are there numbers in the rest of the text?)

The numerical time values have different units; and some numbers have no units at all.

Yes, the time values are all free text entered by humans unfortunately.

My proposal would be to ignore the bracketing problem -- not all your examples contain paired brackets of any sort anyway -- and instead concentrate on numbers in the acceptable range.
    time_matches = re.seach(r"\b\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?:h(?:rs?)?|m(?:in)?)?\b", entry)

This switches from findall to just search; none of your examples contain more than one time expression.
This is still quite heuristical. If you want to tighten it up some, you might want to specify that hours must be a single digit (or at least less than, let's say sixteen?) and minutes must be double digits. Then, you can also allow hours followed by minutes, rather than require just a single number. But none of your examples require that, so I didn't go there.
Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yUUhGH/1
Without requiring units or strict formatting conventions it is inherently impossible to cope with hypothetical entries like

work on project 2 (3)

to indicate 3 hours of work.
Problems like this is why bureaucrats like forms where you can only submit exactly the required information in a tightly specified format. Then it's easy to process, but impossible to handle cases which somehow require special handling or manual review or interaction.
Eventually, if you require high precision without human review, a system which requires submitters to break up entries into "what" and "for how long", where only hh:mm input is permitted for the latter, might be the best solution; or, perhaps some sort of NLP system to try to make sense of the text based on linguistic analysis (but even then, I can't see how that could be foolproof).

Thanks tripleee, really appreciate it the feedback. I agree 100%, the best solution would be for the capturing system to be adjusted to cater for the exact duration in a universal format.
